# Is it normal for gradle to load up build for an hour and still counting

Tags: android, mobile, gradle

I cannot open Android Studio, so changing gradle preference is not an option. I'm on standstill on gradle at the start up... for over an hour.

[image: Stuck on gradle]

Any help would be great and deleting .gradle folder doesn't help either.

**UPDATE**  (TOOK 15 minutes to do a gradlew debug and 45 mins from SDK to update new SDK platforms and tools)

Still no success, however I am still working on it. I provided screenshots to help you see where I am.

[image: Debug Log]

Comment: Are you on a corporate network? Some corporate networks have proxy configurations that break SSL, and thus Gradle can't connect to securely connect to repositories such as Maven Central. If that's the case, try a different network.

Comment: @Tanis.7x  thank you for your comment. I wish my home was a corporate network, but unfortunately no I do not. But it is a good suggestion because the basic project does connect to the internet.  I did a further debug from the gentleman's comment below for "gradlew" and found it was tracing back to the sdk which may be the problem. But I cannot confirm yet if it is. I am still trying to fix it from the debug log.  I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on, shut down Android Studio and try to build your project from the command line. Just do

```
./gradlew assembleDebug -i
```

or if you're on Windows

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug -i
```

The `-i` modifier turns on the INFO log level, and you'll see quite a bit of output, which will be helpful in identifying the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi Egor, thank you for the comment. I did the debug.  I found it was tracing back to Sdk issues but I do confirm I have them installed.  But it is still having issues when I reinstall them.   I went back to the path of the "sdk"    C:\User\...App\Data\...android\sdk         and found that it is tracking an empty folder (which I deleted from my previous installation).  I installed the "sdk" in another location, but Android Studio in the debug command is still tracing back to the old local sdk path.          .

Comment: Currently, I am copying the new files into the old local sdk path and see if it will detect the sdk to allow it to progress further.   Thank you for the commands to help me see the logs too.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if you've found it helpful.

Comment: Accepted for helpful debugging process.